# How can Slick use different Database driver based on Application environment (e.g. test, prod, etc.)

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, sbt, slick

Slick 3.0.0
play 2.6.2

I am experimenting with Slick and run into an interesting issue. I hope the solution is just trivial and I am thinking too much about this

I have implemented the following simple code.

```
case class Content(content:String)

class ContentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Content](tag, "content"){
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def content = column[String]("content")


  override def * : ProvenShape[Content] = (content).mapTo[Content]
}

object ContentDb {
  val db = Database.forConfig("databaseConfiguration")
  lazy val contents = TableQuery[ContentTable]

  def all: Seq[Content] = Await.result(db.run(contents.result), 2 seconds)
}
```

So for this code to work, it requires the following import among others of course.

```
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._
```

or alternatively

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
```

Now, I think, and please correct me if I am wrong, that the database driver should be a configuration detail. That is, I'd choose to run H2 in memory database while developing. Run against test PostgreSQL instance when testing and then run against another instance when in production. I mean the whole idea of abstracting the driver is to have this flexibility... I think.

Now, I have done some research and found that I could do something like this:

```
trait DbComponent {

  val driver: JdbcProfile

  import driver.api._

  val db: Database

}


trait H2DbComponent extends DbComponent {

  val driver: JdbcProfile = slick.jdbc.H2Profile

  import driver.api._

  val db = Database.forConfig("databaseConfiguration")

}

trait Contents {
  def all: Seq[Content]
}

object Contents {
  def apply: Contents = new ContentsDb with H2DbComponent
}

trait ContentsDb extends Contents {
  this: DbComponent =>

  import driver.api._

  class ContentTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Content](tag, "content") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def content = column[String]("content")


    override def * : ProvenShape[Content] = content.mapTo[Content]
  }

  lazy val contents = TableQuery[ContentTable]

  def all: Seq[Content] = Await.result(db.run(contents.result), 2 seconds)

}
```

Then I can use dependency injection to inject the right instance for each entity that I have. Not ideal, but possible. So, I start digging on how to have conditional dependency injection based on which environment is running in Play Framework.

I was expecting something similar to the following:

```
@Component(env=("prod","test")
class ProductionContentsDb extends ContentsDb with PostgresDbComponent

@Component(env="dev")
class ProductionContentsDb extends ContentsDb with H2DbComponent
```

But, no luck...

**EDIT**

Just after I have finished writing this and started reading it again, I am curious if we can just have the something similar to:

```
class DbComponent @Inject (driver: JdbcProfile) {

  import driver.api._

  val db = Database.forConfig("databaseConfiguration")

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create separate configuration files for each environment. like

```
application.conf --local

application.prod.conf -- prod with contents below

include "aplication.conf"
###update slick configurations
```

Then while running application in different stages feed in with `-Dconfig.resource=`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sourav. How do you pick which environment from within the application?